# API rate limits on calling getSyncChunk()

Tags: evernote

Given that Evernote don't publish their exact API rate limits (at least I can't find them), I'd like to ask for some guidance on it's usage.

I'm creating an application that will sync the user's notes and store them locally.  I'm using `getFilteredSyncChunk` to do this.

I'd like to know how often I can make this API call without hitting the limits. I understand that the limits are on a per-user basis, so would it be acceptable to call this every 5 minutes to get the latest notes?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The rate limit is on a per API key basis. You'll be okay calling `getFilteredSyncChunk` every five minutes, although it's a little more efficient to call [getSyncState](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getSyncState) instead.

In case you haven't seen it yet, check out [this guide](https://dev.evernote.com/media/pdf/edam-sync.pdf) for info on sync (accessible from [this page](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/synchronization.php)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Sorry i should have been more specific, I am using getSyncState to check for changes first, i was just thinking worst case. Thanks again